# How can I return nested entity from other database in json response in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I use Python, Django and DRF.
I have 2 databases.
One of them contains table named "documents" (fields: id, name, document_type_id), second database contains table named 'document_type' (fields: id, name, description).
Field 'document_type_id' from table "document" already filled values from table 'document_type'.
As tell Django documentation: "Django doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases."
Question: How can I show nested entity 'document_type' when serializing entity 'document' in GET requests?

```
Example entity 'document':
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "document_name",
  "document_type": {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "passport",
    "description": "identity document"
  }


Example list of 'documents':
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "document_name",
  "document_type": {
    "id": 25,
    "name": "passport",
    "description": "identity document"
  },
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "document_name2",
  "document_type": {
    "id": 24,
    "name": "reference",
    "description": "reference document"
  }
```

Model's code (models.py)

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    document_type_id = models.BigIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "documents"
        managed = False

class DocumentType(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "document_type"
        managed = False
```

Serializer's code (serializer.py)

```
class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'document_type')


class DocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentType
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')
```

View's code (views.py)

```
class DocumentDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer


class DocumentListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Document.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentSerializer


class DocumentTypeView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = DocumentType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentTypeSerializer

class DocumentTypeListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = DocumentType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentTypeSerializer
```

Comment: Is this single value or list?

Comment: It can be single value or list.

Comment: Can you add your view code so I can show you example in context of your code

Comment: I added code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't have anything that will help you achieve this. So you will have to do stitch everything manually

Add nested serializer `DocumentTypeSerializer` to `DocumentSerializer`. And change [`to_representation`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj) on `DocumentSerializer` and it's [`ListSerialzer`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer)

```
class DocumentTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DocumentType
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description')

class DocumentListSerialzer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, data):
        _qs = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        dt_mapping = {dt.id: dt for dt in DocumentType.objects.all()}
        documents = []
        for d in _qs:
            d.document_type = dt_mapping[d.document_type_id]
            documents.append(d)
        return documents

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    document_type = DocumentTypeSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'document_type')
        list_serializer_class = DocumentListSerialzer

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj.document_type = DocumentType.objects.get(id=obj.document_type_id)
        return obj
```